# Factorial of a non-integer number

Tags: number-theory, factorial

My TI-83 calculator doesnt allow me to do this, but using Windows calculator, I can compute the factorial of say 5.8. What does this mean and how does it work?

Comment: As I recall, these calculators can compute factorials of half-integers. But yes, you need $\Gamma(z)$ in general.

Comment: Out of interest, what value do you get for $5.8!$? If it's based on the gamma function, you would get around $496.606\ldots$. (Everyone's mentioned the gamma function here, which is the most likely candidate, but there are other possible extensions of the factorial function to non-integers)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for the Gamma function. It restricts to the usual factorial on natural numbers.

[Wikipedia's article on Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)